# A car speed doubles every 1 minute how fast does it go after 5 minutes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a car starts at 1 mph, and its speed doubles after every minute, how fast does it go after 5 minutes?  I said 32 mph, but my solution says 16 mph.  However, I don't see how this is true.  Since

0 minutes - 1 mph

1 minute - 2 mph

2 minutes - 4 mph

3 minutes - 8 mph

4 mintes - 16 mph

5 minutes - 32 mph

Comment: The problem's wording is very problematic, to say the least, and if you were given

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just a simple misunderstanding.  What you probably mean to say is the following:

After $0$ minutes: $1$ mph
After $1$ minute: $2$ mph
After $2$ minutes: $4$ mph
After $3$ minutes: $8$ mph
After $4$ minutes: $16$ mph

But what you actually mean is:

$1$st minute: $1$ mph
$2$nd minute: $2$ mph
$3$rd minute: $4$ mph
$4$th minute: $8$ mph
$5$th minute: $16$ mph

The only ambiguity is how long the car is supposed to go $1$ mph.  If the car starts at $1$ mph and *instantly* jumps to $2$ mph, then you are correct.  However, if the car is supposed to go $1$ mph for the first minute, then that is why you are incorrect.  I would imagine the second interpretation is what was intended.

Comment: I think this is actually what he means. Because he also specified the speed doubles after the minute, so it seems legit.